# Method signature is not recognized properly when calling it (No overload for method xxx takes 2 arguments)

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm working on some simple utilities for unit testing Stored Procedures, scripts, and so on.  I have this extension method signature:

```
public static List<List<dynamic>> RunScript(this SqlConnection conn, string command, params object[] args)
```

Which somehow is generating a compile error with this attempted call:

```
conn.RunScript("DELETE FROM BE_Resources WHERE CreatedByContactId = {0}", org);
```

Where `org` is an `int`.

> Error 2   No overload for method 'RunScript' takes 2 arguments    C:\GIT\MainLine\tests\BE2.Database.Tests\GroupedAuthorizations\GroupedAuthorizationsUnitsTests.cs   171 13  BE2.Database.Tests

When navigating in the code, F-12 does indeed take me to this method. Also, shift F-12 produces the same number of hits as a global text search.

I made a new extension method `RunScriptTWO`, and now I get compile errors trying to call *that* - compiler just can't find it. Then I sabatoge my original RunScript method, by typing an XXX next to the name. Hitting F-12 to go to definition now breaks, but the project compiles, and all my tests still pass.

I've cleaned my solution and re-built numerous times. It seems like some sort of internal representation of the RunScript method is just out of date, and all my attempts to refresh it are failing miserably.

I'm not able to reproduce this very error with a more trivial example.  (ie, a simple extension method on object taking a string parameter, and params array works fine).

Comment: Does `RunScript(conn, "...", org);` work?

Comment: And what happens when you debug it? Is it possible you have another `RunScript` method somewhere and its instead finding that one?

Comment: The code compiles just fine for me.  You'll need to provide a complete example that can replicate the problem.

Comment: @Jamiec It's not compiling, so he couldn't debug it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a little bit stupid, What I meant was when you navigate to the code from your unit test does it find the method you're expecting.

Comment: @Jamiec - yes, F-12 does indeed take me to this method.  Also, shift F-12 produces the same number of hits as a global text search.

Comment: As an aside, I'm sure you've heard the dangers of non-parameterized queries. That extension method seems to lend itself to that danger.

Comment: Out of curiousity, which framework version is your project targeting?

Comment: @GrantWinney If it were it'd be using a different formatting placeholder.

Comment: Is there an Error 1?

Comment: @Adam, just curious since I've seen strange behavior with params in extension methods when I have overloads of the same method.  I can't reproduce this in Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2012.  Do you have any overloads of that extension method that could be confusing the compiler?

Comment: This is incredibly weird.  I made a new extension method RunScriptTWO, and now I get compile errors trying to call *that* - compiler just can't find it.

Comment: Then I sabatoge my original RunScript method, by typing an XXX next to the name.  Hitting F-12 to go to definition now breaks, but the project compiles, and all my tests still pass.  I've cleaned my solution and re-built numerous times.  This is just ... bizarre.

Comment: It's seems like some sort of internal representation of the RunScript method is just out of date, and all my attempts to refresh it are failing miserably.

Comment: This sounds like one or more of your projects aren't building.  Can you check your configuration manager for which projects are set to build?

Comment: @Alan - that's it.  I just did that - I checked the `build` box in configuration manager for the project in question, and that did it.  Please post an answer to that effect so I can close this out.  Bonus points if you mentioned how and why VS could possibly be so stupid to not know to build the project after changes were made therein, and even after a solution clean :(

Comment: Do you have any other errors or warnings?  I've had issues with extension methods before where suddenly all the bindings to extension methods failed, and cleaning/rebuilding fixed the issue.

Comment: @Grant - one of those, certainly.  So what is this "feature" for?  Uncheck the box, do and do some experimental work that won't get built into the solution?

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks @Grant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment chain, this sounds like one or more of your projects aren't building.  You can verify which projects are set to build under Build > Configuration Manager.